# MySQL datetime wrong hour with SELECT

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using datetime type in MySQL, but when I do SELECT request in my NodeJS API, it returns the wrong hour. I tried doing the request with MySQL, and it returns the right time, this only occurs with NodeJS.

Result of a select (formatted in JSON):

```
[
    {
        "id": 24,
        "opponent": "Sarine",
        "location": "Marly Grand-Pré",
        "datetime": "2022-10-14T16:30:00.000Z",
        "team": "U16"
    }
]
```

The time should be 18:30, in the database it IS 18:30.

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.time_zone | @@SESSION.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              |
+--------------------+---------------------+

show create table game;

CREATE TABLE `game` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_reservation` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_team` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_location` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `opponent` varchar(42) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `game_location_id_fk` (`fk_location`),
  KEY `game_team_id_fk` (`fk_team`),
  KEY `game_reservation_id_fk` (`fk_reservation`),
  CONSTRAINT `game_location_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_location`) REFERENCES `location` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `game_reservation_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_reservation`) REFERENCES `reservation` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `game_team_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_team`) REFERENCES `team` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not a timezones issue?

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table yourtablename` and `SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;`

Comment: *"datetime": "2022-10-14T16:30:00.000Z"* MySQL **cannot** return such value while retrieving the value from `DATETIME` column, it will return `'2022-10-14 16:30:00'` (no `T`, `Z`, fractional part in second). This means that you see the value which was processed additionally by Node.JS. I.e. this is not MySQL-side problem. And it must be solved on the client side.

Comment: Try to return the value as a string, not as a datetime. I.e. ```SELECT .., CAST(`datetime` AS CHAR) AS `datetime`, ..```.